# Is a typescript ellipsis a performance concern?

Tags: javascript, performance, typescript

Typescript ellipsis generates JavaScript which constructs an array out of `arguments` at the beginning of the function.

```
function blah(...args: any[]){
}
```

becomes:

```
function blah() {
    var args = [];
    for (var _i = 0; _i < (arguments.length - 0); _i++) {
        args[_i] = arguments[_i + 0];
    }
}
```

Looking over my project with performance in mind, I'm wondering whether this construction is a performance concern for often called code?

Is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to answer that question is to run some tests.  [JsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) is a pretty awesome tool for that.  I was curious myself so I set up a test [over here](http://jsperf.com/typescript-rest-operator) and yes, it could be a significant performance hit.  How much depends on how often you call that function, the amount of work it does and how long the parameter list is likely to get.

All of that said I'm a big believer in the [80/20 rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle), especially when it comes to optimization.  Most of the time it won't matter, so if it makes the code more beautiful go ahead and use it.

Comment: I get some wildly varied results depending on which browser I run the tests on.  IE and FireFox hate working directly with arguments while Chrome is fastest with it.  That's really interesting.

Comment: ... Is meant for "rest" parameters. Not parameters that are arrays. So if you are passing more than say 10 parameters to a function then I think there might be bigger problems

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jeffrey's answer but I think a point has been missed.

You ask whether a rest parameter causes a performance hit, but compared to what?

For example, if I had the following function:

```
var addNums = function(...nums: number[]) {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        result += nums[i];
    }
    return result;
};
```

What alternatives can I use?

If I wanted to avoid the rest parameter, I would probably accept an array argument still given we don't know how many nums there may be. The runtime performance would be similar in these two scenarios. Therefore the rest parameter is just a convenience for the calling code:

```
addNums(1,1,2,3);
```

Rather than

```
addNums([1,1,2,3]);
```

If TypeScript had method overloads with their own function bodies, you could do the same trick that has been used in the C# framework class library, whereby you supply fixed methods for a series of overloads and use the rest parameter to handle cases with greater numbers of arguments - for example you would have method signatures such as:

```
addNums(a: number, b: number)
addNums(a: number, b: number, c: number)
addNums(...nums: number[])
```

So in your common cases, the non-looping version would be called, but in edge cases the less performant version would run.

You *could* try this in TypeScript, but you would need to provide a single compatible method body for all of the overloads and then check the arguments which is unlikely to be faster (although you could measure it).

So unless you are going to call this method a thousand times, it is unlikely to be worse than an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious as well since my log function uses them and is called a lot.

I tested

```
function toArray(obj, start)
{
  var arr=[];
  for (var i=start||0, j=0, len=obj.length; i<len; ++i)
      arr[j++]=obj[i];
  return arr;
}

function toArrayPush(obj, start)
{
  var arr=[];
  for (var i=start||0, len=obj.length; i<len; ++i)
      arr.push(obj[i]);
  return arr;
}

function testArgToArrayPush(level)
{
  var args=toArrayPush(arguments, 1);
}

function testArgToArray(level)
{
  var args=toArray(arguments, 1);
}

function testArgTypescript(level)
{
  var args = [];
  for (var _i = 0; _i < (arguments.length - 1); _i++)
      args[_i] = arguments[_i + 1];
}

function testArgSlice(level)
{
  var args=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
}
```

on node.js v0.10.18 using the excellent benchmarkjs.com:

```
testArgToArrayPush x 4,505,312 ops/sec ±0.55% (64 runs sampled)
testArgToArray x 2,961,857 ops/sec ±2.37% (93 runs sampled)
testArgTypescript x 3,879,242 ops/sec ±1.15% (96 runs sampled)
testArgSlice x 1,060,084 ops/sec ±0.52% (95 runs sampled)
Fastest is testArgToArrayPush
```

That means

- **the Typescript version is good enough for most cases**
- if you have hotspots you might consider using toArrayPush()
- avoid Array.prototype.slice()